# Can't insert Great Britain Pound in ms sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I insert into a column the sign of pound it doesn't show correctly in mssql server 2005 it gives me L when I insert £ . Please any help

Comment: Use UTF-8. `£` is not ASCII.

Comment: I've linked some fiddle where a `NVarChar` column is used to insert and retrieve a `'£'` charachter. Please extend you question with a counter example where this doesn't work. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a91f/1

Comment: ALTER TABLE DEFVALU 
ADD [sign] nvarchar(5) null 

UPDATE DEFVALU set [sign]='£'
WHERE code='0006'

Comment: I fixed id just added UPDATE DEFVALU set [sign]=N'£' WHERE code='0006'

Comment: @user2830510 - in the future, please update the question itself (there should be an 'edit' link, just below the tags) when you have extra information.

Comment: The thing you need to do is to accept Damiens answer! and not copy it in comments here.

Answer (score 1):

Use an [`NVarChar`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) or [`NChar`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) column type instead of `VarChar` or `Char`.

---

I've [linked some fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9a91f/1) where a `NVarChar` column is used to insert and retrieve a `'£'` character. Please extend your question with a counter example where this doesn't work.

Comment: My column is nvarchar

Comment: ALTER TABLE ttable
ADD [sign] nvarchar(5) null

Comment: @user2830510, extend the question with this example and information.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use characters outside of the database collation's range of characters - a.k.a an nvarchar literal - you need to prefix the opening quote character with an `N`:

```
UPDATE DEFVALU set [sign]=N'£' WHERE code='0006'
```